# Why can't we use page views instead of events in Site Catalyst

Tags: adobe-analytics

We have a requirement to capture the number of users who successfully logged in or updated his/her profile.
On reading about this, we see that `events` are the right ones to use to capture this metric.
Just wondering, why can't we use the `s.pageName` to know the number of successful logins? We set a particular pagename to that variable, and the count of that page name tells us the number of successful logins or updated his/her profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated metric for your count of page views on the success page in Adobe Analytics as an alternative to capturing an event.

Answer (score 0):

They are just different and have different advantages.

One reason using events can be helpful is that you could track an event across multiple domains or if you want to track different types of registrations (popup vs checkout). My employer runs dozens of websites and events are very useful to track errors across domains or checkout events.

Using a calculate metric can be very powerful as well. The biggest strength here being that (hopefully) you have been tracking pageNames since day one. If you use an event to add tracking, you will get tracking from the day you tagged it. If you use a calculated metric, you will be able to retroactively see data from years past.

Generally, we use a calculate metric in most cases where it doesn't provide any data issues.